# SQL get attribute of attribute of foreign key

Tags: sql, foreign-keys, join

I need some help with building a SQL statement. I have two tables.

1. Table `categories` with columns `name` and `parent`, where `parent` references the ID of itself.

For example:

```
ID     name      parent
-------------------------
1      Fruit      Null
2      Banana       1
3      Apple        1
```

2. Table `Fooddiary` with columns `examplecol1, examplecol2, "categorie`, where `categorie` references the ID of `categories`

Now I want to get for example all `Fooddiary` entries where `examplecol1 == "test"`, in a form like:

```
Categorie    Subcategorie    examplecol1     examplecol2
---------------------------------------------------------
Fruit        Banana           test             a
Fruit        Banana           test             b
Fruit        Apple            test             a
```

I tried a join like:

```
Select 
    categories.name, categories.parent, 
    examplecol1, examplecol2 
from 
    Fooddiary
join 
    categories on categorie = categories.id 
where 
    examplecol1=="test";
```

This works except the fact that in my result column `Categorie` there is the parent ID and not the name. So what I am looking for is something like:

```
Select 
    categories.name, categories.parent.name, 
    examplecol1, examplecol2 
from 
    Fooddiary 
join 
    categories on categorie = categories.id 
where 
    examplecol1 == "test";
```

Can somebody help how to solve this?

Comment: I am surprised that "this works". The equality operator in SQL is `=`, not `==`. And string constants need to be specified with single quotes in SQL. `"test"` refers to a column name in (standard SQL). `'test'` is a string constant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for this?

```
       select cat.NAME, cat.PARENT, parents.NAME, fd.EXAMPLECOL1, fd.EXAMPLECOL2
         from FOODDIARY fd
   inner join CATEGORIES cat on fd.CATEGORIE = cat.ID
    left join CATEGORIES parents on cat.PARENT = parents.ID
        where fd.EXAMPLECOL1 = 'test'
```